# $\sum f_n$ converges in $L^p(\mu)$ implies $\|f_n\|_p \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I need some help on a measure theory question.
If a function series  $\sum f_n$ converges in $L^p(\mu)$ this implies $\|f_n\|p \to 0$ as  $n\to+\infty$.

How can I show this?
I thought about using dominate convergence theorem since, $\sum f_n <+\infty$ almost anywhere, then $f_n(x)\to0$ almost anywhere. But I can't find a dominating function, unless $|f_n| \leq |\sum f_n|$.
I kindly thank anyone who would like to help.

Comment: Cauchy property.  $L_p$ is a complete metric space.

Comment: @GEdgar Where does completeness come in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $S_n$ is the $n-$th partial sum then $f_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$ so $||f_n||_p =\|S_n-S_{n-1}||_p \leq \|S_n-S||_p+\|S-S_{n-1}||_p \to 0$ (where $S=\sum f_n$). Completeness is not involved  and it is it not true that $\sum \|f_n\|_p <\infty$ [Convergence does not imply absolute convergence even for series of constants.].

Explicit counter-example to $\sum \|f_n\|_p <\infty$: $f_n =\chi_{(0,1)} \frac {(-1)^{n}} n$.

Comment: This answer is correct imo. However I wouldn't suggest addressing other answer's/comment's problems in one's own answer, so that the thread does not become chaotic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the counter-example!! Very useful

Comment: My thought was: if $\sum f_n$ converges then $S_n$ is Cauchy, and then $f_n = S_{n}-S_ {n-1} \to 0$.  But (as pointed out here) this direction of [converge iff Cauchy] does not need completeness.